# Node Modules / Working with Firebase in Node Js - how to retrieve images in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

I have an html page that can view images from my firebase app. However, this also exposes my firebase credentials as its client side.

What I'd like to do is accomplish the same in node js. but have issues/lack of understanding of node modules.

here is my redacted HTML/javascript

```
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.12.1/firebase-app.js";
import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.12.1/firebase-analytics.js";
import { getAuth } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.12.1/firebase-auth.js'
import { getFirestore, collection, addDoc,getDocs, doc, updateDoc, deleteDoc } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.12.1/firebase-firestore.js'
import { getStorage, ref, uploadBytesResumable, getDownloadURL } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.12.1/firebase-storage.js'

const param = {
apiKey:"mykey",
authDomain: "xxxm",projectId: "mobxxxes",storageBucket: "mobxxxxxt.com",messagingSenderId: "83xxxx7",
appId: "1:xxx2047:web:79xxx7a",measurementId: "G-ZxxxxxxxxH"
};


const app = initializeApp(param);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
const db = getFirestore(app);
const storage = getStorage(app);



async function loadImages(){
let querySnapshot = await getAllData();
let divPag = $("#uploaded_images");

setTimeout(()=>{
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
myImageSrc.push(imageSrc(doc.data(),doc.id));
myImageDes.push(imageDescription(doc.data(),doc.id));

});
},1000)

}

function imageSrc(image,i){
let data =`${image["src"]}`
return data;
}
function imageDescription(image,i){
let data =`${image["description"]}`
return data;
}


loadImages();


})
```

Tried to accomplish in node but errors regarding modules/importing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in package.json add

```
 "type":"module",
```

as for the rest of the node console app use the following and change credentials

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getFirestore, collection, getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore/lite';
// Follow this pattern to import other Firebase services
// import { } from 'firebase/<service>';

let myArr = [];

// TODO: Replace the following with your app's Firebase project configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  
//my creds here
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app);

// Get a list of cities from your database
async function getCities() {
  const citiesCol = collection(db, "uploadedimages");
  const citySnapshot = await getDocs(citiesCol);
  const cityList = citySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
  myArr.push(cityList);
console.log(myArr[0][0].src)

  //return cityList;
}

getCities();
```